# Cant access the Style tab of joomla from back end

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.3

i have created a joomla backend template everything works fine, new template displays all the content easily on the site, also new style is implemented too , but when i try to access the Style of the current template from back end this is what i get **Template Manager -> Styles->my Template.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there an error should exist in your template's XML file, it can even be a syntax error or any inconsistency in the names (template name with folder name). Go through it and check everything carefully.